# How to connect a svelte frontend with a Python API?

Tags: python, json, frontend, backend, svelte

I am very new to web development. But, so far I have created a "front.svelte" file that looks as I want with fake data directly logged in the components (charts from Apexcharts for example), and I also have a "back.py" file with several functions that return raw-type lists and arrays. I was hoping I could do something as:

1. Run the "back.py" file in a localhost port
2. Runt the "front.svelte" file in another localhost port
3. From "front.svelte" call a function fun(param1, param2) in "back.py", where param1, param2 are obtained from inputs of the svelte's localhost port.
4. Convert the returned objects to .json format
5. Use the .jsons in 4 as the "data:" input for a chart/table in the "front.svelte" file.

I don't know if this is possible or where to even start, or if I wasted my time creating the back.py file. Any type of guidance on where can I find more info or some examples is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is a very typical frontend-backend setup, usually called an 'API' (the backend part). The two parts are separate from each other as Svelte runs on the client (browser) and your Python on the server, this means you cannot 'call a function' from one to the other.

What you do is use `fetch` to contact an "endpoint" from your server that then returns the requested data.  You can easily find tutorials on how to set up a basic server to do so in Python, just search for "writing an API with Python". (not very familiar with Python myself).

For `fetch` you can check out the documentation on MDN.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API